# Spark Java code that works fine in Eclipse IDE throws ClassNotFoundException while running the jar generated by maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, executable-jar, nats.io

I'm using below Java Spark code to connect to NATS.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .appName("spark-with-nats")
                    .master("local")
                    .config("spark.jars",
                      "libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar,"+"libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar")
                    .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation","tmp/checkpoint")
                    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
                    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
                      .getOrCreate();
            
            Dataset<Row> df = spark.readStream()
                    .format("nats")
                    .option("nats.host", "localhost")
                    .option("nats.port", 4222)
                    .option("nats.stream.name", "newstream")
                    .option("nats.stream.subjects", "newsub")
                    .option("nats.durable.name", "cons1")
                    .option("nats.msg.ack.wait.secs", 120)
                    .load();
```

2 External jars that I'm using while creating sparkSession are present under "libs" folder and have been added to the classpath

```
.config("spark.jars","libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar,"+"libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar")
```

[image]

[image]

This code works fine when I run from Eclipse IDE. Now I'm building a jar out of it using maven pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- *** COMMENT START **********

    <dependency>
        <groupId>external.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>external.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>jnats</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency> 

    *** COMMENT END ********** -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.optiva.MinIOTester</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I run the generated jar by providing the libs folder ( with 2 external jars) in the classpath

```
java -cp "../libs/*.jar" -jar spark-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: nats. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:144)
        at com.test.MinIOTester.sparkNatsTesterNewOnLocal(MinIOTester.java:387)
        at com.test.MinIOTester.main(MinIOTester.java:31)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nats.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
```

If I see the error **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nats.DefaultSource** looks like it's not making use of the 2 external jars that we are adding to the classpath while running `java -cp "../libs/*.jar"` command . I tried with giving absolute path for the external jar folder and even jar names. But still getting same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you are referring to `libs/something.jar` in your config but use `-cp ../libs/*` in your command line. Are the libraries in `libs` or in `../libs` relative to where you launch that command?

Comment: Oh, also: `-cp` is ignored when using `-jar`, as only the classpath specified in the jar file will be used.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes. It's relative. I even tried using absolute path for libs folder. I can also see 23/12/19 13:34:25 INFO Executor: Adding file:/....foldernames/jnats-2.17.1.jar to class loader for both of the jars in the logs.  Sorry didn't understand " also: -cp is ignored when using -jar, as only the classpath specified in the jar file will be used." Can you elaborate please . What command should I use ?

Comment: Update : I can also see 23/12/19 13:34:25 INFO Executor: Adding file:/....foldernames/jnats-2.17.1.jar to class loader for both of the jars in the logs -> This one is because I'm referring those 2 jars inside my java code `.config("spark.jars","libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar,"+"libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar")` and not because of -cp command. Tested by passing wrong libs foldername to -cp command and it still printed above logs.

Answer (score 1):

It ran successfully by using spark-submit command by passing external dependencies in the classpath

```
spark-submit --jars libs/nats-spark-connector-balanced_2.12-1.1.4.jar,libs/jnats-2.17.1.jar spark-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Thanks @JoachimSauer for the hint that "-cp is ignored when using -jar, as only the classpath specified in the jar file will be used" . In my earlier command as I was using java -jar, -cp was getting ignored.